# MySQL select random row - rand() performance

Tags: php, mysql

Is it true that `ORDER BY rand()` performance is very slow compared to other solutions? If yes, what are better ways to select random row(s) from the database?

My query:

```
SELECT sName FROM bpoint WHERE placeID=? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It depends on how much data there is. How big table are we talking about?

Comment: It also depends on what, exactly, you mean by "random": do you require every record be selected with equal probability?  Or is a perfectly uniform distribution not necessary?

Comment: 5-10.000 rows. Equal probability desired.

Comment: If you know that an indexed column contains values ranging from `i` to `j`, you could filter `WHERE column >= FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i)) ORDER BY column LIMIT 1`.  But if there are gaps, you won't obtain a perfectly uniform distribution of probabilities...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `ORDER BY RAND()` can be very slow in larger result-sets.

An option is to fetch resultset with this statement (into an array):

```
SELECT sName FROM bpoint WHERE placeID=?;
```

After that - use `array_rand($resultset)` to get a randomized item from the `$resultset` query.

Comment: So, it is php function array_rand() faster?

Comment: @JamaicaBob - it really depends on how large the resultset is. How many rows do you have in your table bpoint?

Comment: approximately 10.000 rows

Comment: @JamaicaBob - ok, I THINK it would be faster with an array then, but I'm not sure. I guess you will just have to test and see difference. How long does the actual query take now?

Comment: Okay will do some tests and report :)

Comment: @BikerJohn - Older question, but depending on your programming language, php has mt_rand(). I implemented this by doing a quick count of the number of rows I have, and then doing $random = mt_rand(1,$count) to get a random int in the range, then SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE ID = $random; Performance numbers jumped significantly. Only works if you have unique IDs though (auto_increment ftw!)

Comment: @Wes What happens if you delete a row from table and mt_rand() gives you a non-existing ID? Your query would return an empty resultset. A much better solution that is guaranteed to return a result:
$random = mt_rand(0, $count-1);
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $random, 1;
And you don't need an auto incremented field for this to work.

Comment: @pauk960 so your solution would not return an empty result set, but I would be very interested to see the performance numbers of using LIMIT vs a direct select on an indexed field. I wrote my original response over a year ago and we have recently moved to an even faster solution that relies on precomputing the indexed IDs.

Comment: So the mysql is not good because the table is too big but then the php is ok because of what? And this is considered a solution - I'm disappointed. Start learning MySQL and don't cut corners.